# Fetch no envía el body

Tags: javascript, api, express, fetch, http-post

> Hola buenas, tengo el problema que cuando envía una solicitud con fetch no sé envía el body. Intenté cambiar el content-type pero en el servidor (express) cuando imprimo en el router.post se imprime un objeto vacío. Gracias de antemano!

```
function setNewProduct (event) {
event.preventDefault()
const URL = '/api/productos'
const datos = { 
    title: document.getElementById('title').value,
    price: document.getElementById('price').value,
    thumbnail: document.getElementById('thumbnail').value
}
const options = {
    method: 'POST',
    body: JSON.stringify(datos),
    headers: {
        "Content-type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8"
    }
}

console.log(options) // Acá en el cliente se imprime el body ok

fetch(URL, options)
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(dat => console.log(dat))
    .catch(err => console.log(err))}
```

Esto es de express

```
router.post('/', (req, res) => {
console.log(req.body)}) // Acá en la consola del server se imprime un objeto vacío {} cuando llamo a fetch desde el cliente
```

Comment: Tal vez te falta usar un parser para la solicitud. Express trae su propio parser (si usas la versión 4.17 o superior de Express). Verifica que al instanciar tu aplicación, haces uso del parser con `app.use(express.json());` y también `app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));`. Comenta el resultado.

Comment: @MauricioContreras Justo iba a poner eso como respuesta. Igual publícala para cerrar la pregunta.

Comment: Era el app.use(express.json()), gracias!¡

Answer (score 1):

Tal vez te falta usar un parser para la solicitud. Express trae su propio parser (si usas la [versión 4.16 o superior de Express](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#express.json)). Verifica que al instanciar tu aplicación, haces uso del parser de esta manera:

```js
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

// el siguiente middleware hace el parse del cuerpo de la solicitud
// cuando el mismo viene en formato JSON (application/json)
app.use(express.json());

// el siguiente middleware hace el parse del cuerpo de la solicitud
// cuando el mismo se compone de un form data (application/x-www-form-urlencoded)
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
...
```

De esta forma, el objeto `body` de la solicitud contendrá los datos que has enviado desde el cliente.

Nota:

Esto no incluye los datos de tipo `multipart/form-data` (archivos). Para realizar el parse de archivos (uploads al servidor de Express), puedes apoyarte de alguna otra librería, como por ejemplo: [multer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer).